# Pyodbc on Mac connection issues

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc, freetds

I have FreeTDS, unixODBC in my python 3.6.1 installation
I'm trying to get pyodbc connected to my sql server (local VM) . I have tried the following to test configuration of freetds

tsql -S servername -U pydata

I get the following message

Error 20012 (severity 2):
    Server name not found in configuration files.
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20013 (severity 2):
    Unknown host machine name.
There was a problem connecting to the server

however if I use tsql -S 10.0.0.123 -U pydata -P password
i connect just fine with no issues.  I have triple checked the Freetds.conf file as well as the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files.

Anyone have any ideas why my entry for the server is not working?

Comment: Check `tsql -C` to ensure that you are looking at the same freetds.conf directory that FreeTDS is using. Also, your `tsql` command is using the `servername` defined in freetds.conf, not a DSN name defined in odbc.ini, correct?

Comment: Awesome Gord Thompson, that was the problem.  Why does this have to be so confusing?  Well I am just learning this so....
Thank you again Gord Thompson