# Why does pyodbc not import in Python 3.6.4 on macOS 10.13.2

Tags: import, python-3.6, pyodbc, macos-high-sierra

I want to use pyodbc to connect to an .mdb database.  I have pyodbc installed and also freetds --with-unixodbc.  For what I can see the installation is ok.  However, I'm new in coding and I can be doing anything wrong...
I'm sorry if my question is redundant. I did find some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167524/pyodbc-on-mac-connection-issues) on the topic but I was still unable to solve this issue.

```
import pyodbc
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Please let me know what other information I should provide.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not using a `virtualenv`, and you probably installed with a command like `sudo pip install pyodbc`. That version of `pip` is likely for Python 2. First, I'd recommend learning how to use virtualenvs, even if you're new. But regardless, perhaps try `pip3 install pyodbc`?

Comment: Hi FlipperPA, thanks for your reply.  I did try pip first which indeed failed and got it done with pip3 install.  I'll look into virtualenv.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer - I'm glad you got it figured!

Answer (score 0):

The command `pip` installs packages alongside the system Python, which is Python 2.7.x.

You will want to use the command `pip3` instead, which will install packages with the Python 3.6.x version you installed. Good luck!